# Capybara Rspec tests fail unless I use selenium webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, sinatra, capybara

I am currently writing a rock paper scissors program for a course I am on.

My feature test file is as follows...

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'tilt/erb'
require './lib/computer.rb'


  feature 'user can play rock, paper, scissors..' do

    let(:computer){double :computer}

    # before do
    #   include Capybara::DSL
    #   Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
    # end

    scenario 'user can enter their name' do
      sign_in
      expect(page).to have_content "Player Name = Reiss"
    end

    scenario 'page has buttons that allows the user to select a move' do
      sign_in
      click_button('Rock')
    end

    scenario 'see what move the computer played' do
      sign_in
      click_button("Rock")
      expect(page).to have_content "The Computer Played"
    end

    scenario 'see what move the computer played' do
      sign_in
      click_button("Paper")
      expect(page).to have_content "You Played Paper"
    end

    scenario 'player plays Rock & either wins or looses' do
      sign_in
      click_button('Rock')
      expect(page).to have_content "Game Result:"
    end

    scenario 'player plays Paper & either wins or looses' do
      sign_in
      click_button('Paper')
      expect(page).to have_content "Game Result:"
    end

    scenario 'player plays Scissors & either wins or looses' do
      sign_in
      click_button('Scissors')
      expect(page).to have_content "Game Result:"
    end

    scenario 'user can play another round if they want to' do
      sign_in
      click_button('Scissors')
      click_button('Play Again')
      expect(page).to have_content "Player Name = Reiss"
    end
  end
```

My problem is that when I don't include the Capybara DSL & default driver loop up-top my tests fail. When the loop isn't commented out. It opens in firefox and runs through the tests which then all pass. When it doesn't do this rspec fails my test. The first error is that it cannot find my name on the page, the rest all cannot seem to find the button on their respective page. But again, when I run it with selenium they are all fine. I wouldn't normally be bothered but my code is being checked with travis CI on a pull request and so therefore it isn't passing currently!

Could anybody shed some light?

Comment: Is your app dependent on JS?

Comment: If it is (JS dependent) you may want to have a look at one of the headless drivers (webkit or poltergeist) - makes CI easier and you get rid of the annoying firefox pops.